# My laptop refuses to connect with the TP Link wa801nd wifi wireless access point on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: wireless, tp-link

My wifi doesn't manage to connect to an access point. It used to work or work after a laptop restart or on/off, but recently it's getting impossible.

My questions is how i can create some troubleshooting step by step workflow, that i can go through each time and find what is the problem and research the solution.

I had the impression that this was related with my wifi controller or such, but when i turn on my mobile hotspot, it is able to connect to it. so for some reason this is related with the TP Link access point-laptop connection.

Please let me know if you want me to provide any further logs, for the moment these are the ones that i consider relevant:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201     [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Rivet Networks Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [1a56:1651]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger     Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a0e8] (rev 20)

sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
    5.415338] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.422855] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x3617, cnv-id     0x20000302 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    5.422927] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev a0f0/1651, rev=0x351, rfid=0x10a100
[    5.432115] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    5.432133] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    5.432621] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 77.2df8986f.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.591063] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX203, REV=0x351
[    5.715612] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    5.781876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 94:e7:0b:c8:49:a7
[    5.810431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[    6.753820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
```

Restart of the Network manager does not help

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```